# Executing same asynctask multiple times with different params

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

I know there are a lot of question regarding how to run the same asynctask in parallel: what i need is to execute the same asynctask but with different params per task.

I have:

```
MyTask taskOne = new MyTask();
MyTask taskOne = new MyTask();
taskOne.execute(UrlOne);
taskTwo.execute(UrlTwo);
```

MyTask have to download the page from the urlone and url two. When one of the two finishes, i kill the other one with cancel(true). But how can i run those thread in parallel?

If i try this, when taskOne ends it just kill taskTwo.

Thanks all for help

Comment: use a executor for this purpose. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask_parallel. check 6.3 6.3. Parallel execution of several AsyncTasks

Comment: from where you are calling `candel(true)`

Comment: use `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have used some synchronization mechanism like a semaphore or a conditionobject.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZ9NgFYEMxp4tbiFYip6tDNIEBRUDyPQK